# Pairwise K-Means in R

Tags: r, k-means

I have a `dataset` and I want to apply `K-means clustering` to make groups. But, I only want to consider pairs of variables.

The `dataset` has a class variable, so I want this class variable not to take part in the clustering and use it to evaluate algorithm performance.

I want to do it automatically so all possible combinations of two variables must be tried and only the best one returned.

How can I do this in R? 
You can use Iris dataset as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO! What about something like this, to have all the models (and everything about them, to have only the best combination, look the bottom of the answer):

```
# first the pairwise combination of column, without the labels
comb <- combn(names(iris[,-5]),2,simplify=FALSE)
# an empty list to populate with kmeans
listed <- list()
```

Then a for loop that apply the kmeans to each subset, and put the output in the list:

```
for (i in c(1:length(comb))){
  names_ <- comb[[i]]
  df <-iris[ , which(names(iris) %in% names_)]
  listed[[i]] <- kmeans(df,3)
  }
```

As example, here

```
listed[[2]]
K-means clustering with 3 clusters of sizes 51, 58, 41

Cluster means:
  Sepal.Length Petal.Length
1     5.007843     1.492157
2     5.874138     4.393103
3     6.839024     5.678049

Clustering vector:
  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 [66] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 3 2 2 3 3
[131] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 2

Within cluster sum of squares by cluster:
[1]  9.893725 23.508448 20.407805
 (between_SS / total_SS =  90.5 %)

Available components:

[1] "cluster"      "centers"      "totss"        "withinss"     "tot.withinss" "betweenss"    "size"         "iter"        
[9] "ifault"
```

In case you only want the "best" model, in this case the one with the best [purity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#External_evaluation) index (note: I've never used it, so check the formula )ratio, here another loop:

```
# combinations
comb <- combn(names(iris[,-5]),2,simplify=FALSE)
# another list
listed_1 <- list()

library(dplyr) # external package to make it simpler
for (i in c(1:length(comb))){
  names_ <- comb[[i]]
  df <-iris[ , which(names(iris) %in% names_)]
  km <- kmeans(df,3)
  df <- data.frame(cl = km$cluster, spec =iris$Species, cnt = 1)
  df <- aggregate(df$cnt,list(cl = df$cl,spec= df$spec),sum )
  df <- df %>% group_by(spec) %>% filter(x == max(x)) 
  listed_1[[i]] <- round(sum(df$x)/nrow(iris),2)*100
  }
```

Now you got a list as result: the following commands are going to put together (`cbind`) in a data.frame the list of the result  (`do.call(rbind, listed_1)`) and the combinations (`do.call(rbind, comb)`):

```
res <- cbind(do.call(rbind, listed_1),do.call(rbind, comb))
res[which.max(res[,1]),]
[1] "95"           "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I sort the K-means executions according to the number of instances that belong to the same class (it's purity)?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand the question, could you elaborate it (maybe telling the order you want)?

Comment: What I want is to use purity measure (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#External_evaluation) to order the models. And one more question. I don't understand the `do.call` in this line `cbind(do.call(rbind, listed_1),do.call(rbind, comb))`

Comment: Thank you. Your answer has been really helpful.